# ng-repeat not working in dynamically created HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have stuck in my application, which is based on generating charts. I am dynamically adding HTML content and appending it in DOM using an `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="view in Views"><a href="#">{{view.Title}}</a></li>
```

Now, `ng-repeat` is not working with newly added DOM elements :(
Also, it is working fine if used with static code.

Please help me out.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle link which can help us to solve your problem

Comment: You have to use the `$compile` service to make templates go "alive". Provide a fiddle/plunk to get more detailed help.

Comment: It will work in integration with Sharepoint, so not able to provide fiddle as of now. I will have to make fiddle using dummy code, which i am not in condition to do it now :(

Comment: You have to $compile before adding. However it usually bad idea to add a lot of html by hands, consider using ng-repeat for this.

Comment: Use directives to add HTML contents and the use `compile` or `link` to assign correct controller/ directive